# Specifying a threshold value for list elements in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am printing a list `CI` based on certain operations as shown below. I am trying to specify a `threshold` value for each element in the sublist that if the value is less than this `threshold`, it picks this value. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
km = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
CI=[]
threshold=0.005

for t in range(0, 2):
    CI_t = []
    for i in range(0, len(km)):
        CI1 = 0.001 * (1 - np.exp(-km[i] * t))
        CI_t=threshold if CI_t < threshold
        CI_t.append(CI1)
    CI.append(CI_t)
print("CI =",CI)
```

The error is

```
CI_t=threshold if CI_t < threshold[i]
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The expected output is

```
CI = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005]]
```

Comment: 2 problems here: the algorithm don't return values below the threshold, so the 0.005 is not reached. The `max(CI1 ,threshold)` function can be used instead of CI_t=threshold if CI_t < threshold

Comment: Still the output is different than mine.

Comment: There is a problem in the algo: check the values of `0.001*(1-np.exp(-np.asarray(km)*t))` for t = 0, 1. all values are under the threshold

Comment: `x = y if (z) else w` is correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code produces the output you specified. There would be sublists for every t value, but I changed your code to one loop for demo purposes.

```
import numpy as np

km = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
CI = []
threshold = 0.005

for t in range(0, 1):
    CI_t  = []
    for i in range(0, len(km)):
        CI1 = 0.001 * (1 - np.exp(-km[i] * t))
        if CI1 > threshold:
            CI_t.append(CI1),CI.append(0.0)

        else:
            CI1 = 0.005
            CI_t.append(CI1),CI.append(0.0)
           
  
    CI = ([CI,CI_t])
print("CI =",CI)
```

I edited my answer just now to correct a line in the 'if' statement that applies to all amounts greater than .005 (there aren't any).  You wanted all the returned amounts to be .005 or greater, but some of the commenters may have misinterpreted your question.  Your question was a little confusing in that regard, it's a good thing you provided your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

using the `min()` function, you can compare `CI1` with the threshold and select the smaller value between them. This ensures that if `CI1` is less than the threshold, it will be chosen; otherwise, the threshold value will be selected.

```py
for i in range(0, len(km)):
    CI1 = 0.001 * (1 - np.exp(-km[i] * t))
    CI1 = min(CI1, threshold)  # Apply the threshold condition here <<
    CI_t.append(CI1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct code:

```
import numpy as np

km = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
CI = []
threshold = 0.005

for t in range(0, 2):
    CI_t = []
    for i in range(0, len(km)):
        CI1 = 0.001 * (1 - np.exp(-km[i] * t))
        if CI1 < threshold:
            CI_t.append(CI1)
    CI.append(CI_t)
print("CI =", CI)
```

Output:

```
CI = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0006321205588285577, 0.0008646647167633873, 0.0009502129316321361, 0.0009816843611112657, 0.0009932620530009146]]
```

You can round off the values as per your requirements.

Comment: But the output is different than mine.

Comment: Based on the formula `CI1 = 0.001 * (1 - np.exp(-km[i] * t))` you've mentioned, this is the calculated output. Perhaps, you should update the question description to be more precise.